# Adding mlModel to Swift playground playgroundbook

Tags: swift, swift-playground, wwdc

I am currently working on my WWDC Student Challenge and struggling with adding MlModel to the playground book. Are there a way to drag and drop like like in the xcode? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try to click on the plus button on the top corner of your right, there you have it